# INSERT INTO ... WHERE Twitter API

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter

I've stored some tweets into a database so that I don't get restricted by requests from twitter.

I would like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tweets` (`tweet_id` ,`date` ,`time` ,`tweet` ,`tag`)VALUES ({$tweet['link']},'$formatted_date','$formatted_time','$string','$hash') WHERE `tweet_id` <
```

I want to insert into the database where the tweet_id < $Max

Where $Max is a previous select statement which retrieved the MAX tweet_id from the database. This is to reduce duplicates (I was tired of the duplicate `tweet_id` found MySQL error)

How could this be achieved, I cannot do an INSERT INTO SELECT statement since I am not copying from an existing table and I don't want a dump table where I store everything I grab and then do a INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE from DUMP to the Main table. Nor do I want duplicate unique identifiers within the database.

What is a work around I could do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do either `INSERT IGNORE|REPLACE|ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`
For example, if a tweet is immutable, it is easiest to use `INSERT IGNORE` where tweets with same id will be ignored during the insertion

```
insert ignore into tweets
(tweet_id, `date`, `time`, tweet, tag)
VALUES ({$tweet['link']},'$formatted_date','$formatted_time','$string','$hash');
```